# How to count regex matches in Rust?

Tags: regex, rust

I'd like to count the matches of a regex in a string with Rust. I managed to  print all matches:

```
let re = Regex::new(r"(?i)foo").unwrap();
let result = re.find_iter("This is foo and FOO foo as well as FoO.");
for i in result {
    println!("{}", i.as_str())
}
```

But I fail to simply get the number of matches. I can't find any function that gives me the count. I also tried `size_hint()`, but that does not work as well. Any way I can do that?

[Here](https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Count_occurrences_of_a_substring#Using_Regular_Expressions) is the Scala version of what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You already have the iterator, so just count the number of elements in the iterator:

```
re.find_iter("This is foo and FOO foo as well as FoO.").count()
```

Comment: I'm a little bit embarrassed now...  Thanks a lot!